# Native packaging limit PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I'm going to develop a multi-platform mobile app. I'm deciding between two frameworks: Sencha Touch 2 or JQuery Mobile.
If i use JQuery Mobile, i must package my app with PhoneGap. I read that PhoneGap doesn't allow package greater than 9.5 MB.
Can anyone tell me if it's true?

Thank you!!

Comment: Where did you read about the max package size?

Comment: I read that in some forums. Then, i try to prove and try to package a file larger than 9.5 MB and not let me. This is the message: "File is too large. File must be less than 9.5 MB."

Comment: If you're trying to do a build and that's the error message you're getting, then it seem obvious that you can't build packages larger than 9.5MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my PhoneGap apps is nearly 2GB (lots of video content), so there isn't a limit in the framework.

However, Phonegap Build (or any other cloud based build service) will have more limitations, so you will need to build locally if you are doing more complex apps.

Comment: What tool can I use to build locally? On the website of PhoneGap, I could only find cloud based build service.